# Can't get ModuleId in child control of DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am having a parent control and a child control in DNN.
When i try to get moduleId on page load event of child control i get -1.
Below is the code on child control.

```
Globals.NavigateURL(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID, "PlanSponsorManager", "mid=" + ModuleId);
```

Please Advice how can i get the moduleId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load the child control you need to do something like the following

```
var controlToLoad = "Controls/ArticleList.ascx";
                if (ArticleId > 0)
                {
                    controlToLoad = "Controls/ArticleView.ascx";
                }

                var mbl = (dnnsimplearticleModuleBase)LoadControl(controlToLoad);
                mbl.ModuleConfiguration = ModuleConfiguration;
                mbl.ID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(controlToLoad);
                phViewControl.Controls.Add(mbl);
```

Setting the module configuration is important

Example from http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#cs/View.ascx.cs

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your child control inherits from PortalModuleBase. Nevertheless, I believe that using ModuleId property of such a type of control returns -1 because it's not a declared control in the extension database.
I think you could try to get the parent PortalModuleBase using "Parent.ModuleID".

Comment: child control is inheriting from PortalModuleBase but still it is giving error if i try using Parent.ModuleID

Comment: Sorry, you have to reach back until you get the real PortalModuleBase (the control which is declared in the module definition) using recursively "Parent". Then, you may have to cast it in PortalModuleBase.